# What is the feature/state/type of a noun made "real" with a determiner?

Tags: nouns, terminology, determiners

How do you call the feature/type/state of a noun which has been made "actual/real" with a determiner etc. as opposed to without it:

> Car [in the dictionary]
> A/the/my/this... car.

I read "substantif actualisé/non actualisé" (word for word "actualized substantive", "non actualized substantive") in [French](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) and I'm looking for the equivalent.

Comment: Good question. Is there such a thing? And is it actually real? How can one tell?

Comment: Wikipedia calls them [determiner phrases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determiner_phrase), although the second sentence of the article starts with the word "Controversially" so I'm not sure how widespread this is (it seems to be a generative grammar thing).

Comment: @StuartF "Phrased" noun as opposed to just a noun? "Determined" noun? In the source, this is not something new at all like the generative stuff. Lexical as opposed to? I'm no expert. I can see this concept in some academic papers, not just for nouns but for adjectives too, and sometimes in a collocation such as "actualisé mais pas réalisé" with things which have "actualisateur" capacity etc. Maybe just phrase vs. noun?

Answer (score 1):

In the terminology of Huddleston & Pullum (2002), "a car" is a **noun phrase,** within which "car" is a **nominal.**

Comment: But wouldn't "car" still be a nominal even without a determiner? (E.g.: "When car meets pedestrian, the former usually wins.") In that case, the term "nominal" wouldn't distinguish the determined nominal from the non-determined nominal. OP seems to want the term for the determined nominal "as opposed to without it".

Comment: In still other terminology, _a car_ is a DP, or Determiner Phrase. I spose _car_ by itself is a Dʹ (pronounced "D-bar"), but I'm not sure because I rarely bother to name intermediate nodes in a derivation.